# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: IIOP1004: Key alias s1as not found in keystore

Tags: security, ssl, glassfish, ssl-certificate, glassfish-4.1

I am trying to add a self-signed certificate in GlassFish Server 4.1 for the development purpose only.

The server certificate is generated using the following command.

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\keytool" -genkey -alias
> server-alias -keyalg RSA -keypass changeit -storepass changeit
> -keystore keystore.jks

The server name localhost was taken in response to the keytool's first prompt in which it asks for first and last names.

Added the generated server certificate to the truststore file, cacerts.jks using the following command.

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\keytool" -import -v
> -trustcacerts -alias server-alias -file server.cer -keystore cacerts.jks -keypass changeit -storepass changeit

The default password changeit was left untouched.

The alias s1as was replaced by the alias used in the above commands which is server-alias (under `Configurations->server-config->Http Service->Http Listeners->http-listener-2`, the SSL tab on `http://localhost:4848/`).

keystore.jks and cacerts.jks are stored under `C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\config`.

The JVM options under `Configurations->server-config->JVM Settings`, JVM Options tab on `http://localhost:4848/`, the following options

> -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/keystore.jks
>
> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/cacerts.jks

were already mentioned and they were left untouched.

Since I did not alter the default password changeit, I did not mention the following option therein either.

> -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=new-password

I got the following exception on server start up.

```
Severe: iiop.init_exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: IIOP1004: Key alias s1as not found in keystore
    at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.IIOPSSLUtilImpl.getKeyManagers(IIOPSSLUtilImpl.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.init(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.<init>(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:152)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:438)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ParserTable$4.operate(ParserTable.java:755)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.NormalParserAction.apply(NormalParserAction.java:62)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orb.PropertyParser.parse(PropertyParser.java:84)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orb.ParserImplBase.init(ParserImplBase.java:77)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBDataParserImpl.<init>(ORBDataParserImpl.java:492)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.postInit(ORBImpl.java:562)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.set_parameters(ORBImpl.java:697)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.setParameters(ORBImpl.java:684)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.osgi.ORBFactory.initialize(ORBFactory.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.initORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:585)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.getORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBFactoryImpl.createORB(GlassFishORBFactoryImpl.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:163)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getProtocolManager(GlassFishORBHelper.java:231)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeProtocolManager(BaseContainer.java:898)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.<init>(BaseContainer.java:657)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.<init>(StatelessSessionContainer.java:143)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.<init>(StatelessSessionContainer.java:137)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessContainerFactory.createContainer(StatelessContainerFactory.java:61)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:221)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:313)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:406)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:243)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:329)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:377)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:461)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:84)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2258)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:105)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1162)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1147)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: IIOP1004: Key alias s1as not found in keystore
    at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.IIOPSSLUtilImpl.getKeyManagers(IIOPSSLUtilImpl.java:93)
    ... 47 more

Severe:   enterprise_util.excep_in_createorb
org.omg.CORBA.DATA_CONVERSION: WARNING: 02410014: org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory is not a valid custom socket factory  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 14  completed: No
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy194.badCustomSocketFactory(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ParserTable$4.operate(ParserTable.java:763)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.NormalParserAction.apply(NormalParserAction.java:62)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orb.PropertyParser.parse(PropertyParser.java:84)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orb.ParserImplBase.init(ParserImplBase.java:77)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBDataParserImpl.<init>(ORBDataParserImpl.java:492)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.postInit(ORBImpl.java:562)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.set_parameters(ORBImpl.java:697)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.setParameters(ORBImpl.java:684)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.osgi.ORBFactory.initialize(ORBFactory.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.initORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:585)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.getORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBFactoryImpl.createORB(GlassFishORBFactoryImpl.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:163)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getProtocolManager(GlassFishORBHelper.java:231)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeProtocolManager(BaseContainer.java:898)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.<init>(BaseContainer.java:657)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.<init>(StatelessSessionContainer.java:143)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.<init>(StatelessSessionContainer.java:137)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessContainerFactory.createContainer(StatelessContainerFactory.java:61)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:221)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:313)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:406)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:243)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:329)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:377)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:461)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:84)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2258)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:105)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1162)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1147)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: IIOP1004: Key alias s1as not found in keystore
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.<init>(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:202)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:438)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ParserTable$4.operate(ParserTable.java:755)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: IIOP1004: Key alias s1as not found in keystore
    at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.IIOPSSLUtilImpl.getKeyManagers(IIOPSSLUtilImpl.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.init(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.<init>(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:152)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: IIOP1004: Key alias s1as not found in keystore
    at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.IIOPSSLUtilImpl.getKeyManagers(IIOPSSLUtilImpl.java:93)
    ... 47 more

Severe:   Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer load method
java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization error
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:234)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:313)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:406)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:243)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:329)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:377)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:461)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:84)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2258)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:105)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1162)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1147)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: IIOP Protocol Manager initialization failed.  Possible cause is that ORB is not available in this container
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeProtocolManager(BaseContainer.java:901)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.<init>(BaseContainer.java:657)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.<init>(StatelessSessionContainer.java:143)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.<init>(StatelessSessionContainer.java:137)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessContainerFactory.createContainer(StatelessContainerFactory.java:61)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:221)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Orb initialization erorr
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getProtocolManager(GlassFishORBHelper.java:231)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeProtocolManager(BaseContainer.java:898)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.omg.CORBA.DATA_CONVERSION: WARNING: 02410014: org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory is not a valid custom socket factory  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 14  completed: No
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.initORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:626)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.getORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBFactoryImpl.createORB(GlassFishORBFactoryImpl.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:163)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.DATA_CONVERSION: WARNING: 02410014: org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory is not a valid custom socket factory  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 14  completed: No
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy194.badCustomSocketFactory(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ParserTable$4.operate(ParserTable.java:763)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.NormalParserAction.apply(NormalParserAction.java:62)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orb.PropertyParser.parse(PropertyParser.java:84)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orb.ParserImplBase.init(ParserImplBase.java:77)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBDataParserImpl.<init>(ORBDataParserImpl.java:492)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.postInit(ORBImpl.java:562)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.set_parameters(ORBImpl.java:697)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.setParameters(ORBImpl.java:684)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.osgi.ORBFactory.initialize(ORBFactory.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.initORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:585)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: IIOP1004: Key alias s1as not found in keystore
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.<init>(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:202)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:438)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ParserTable$4.operate(ParserTable.java:755)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: IIOP1004: Key alias s1as not found in keystore
    at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.IIOPSSLUtilImpl.getKeyManagers(IIOPSSLUtilImpl.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.init(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.<init>(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:152)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: IIOP1004: Key alias s1as not found in keystore
    at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.IIOPSSLUtilImpl.getKeyManagers(IIOPSSLUtilImpl.java:93)
    ... 47 more

Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization error
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:234)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:313)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:406)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:243)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:329)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:377)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:461)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:84)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2258)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:105)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1162)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1147)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: IIOP Protocol Manager initialization failed.  Possible cause is that ORB is not available in this container
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeProtocolManager(BaseContainer.java:901)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.<init>(BaseContainer.java:657)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.<init>(StatelessSessionContainer.java:143)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.<init>(StatelessSessionContainer.java:137)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessContainerFactory.createContainer(StatelessContainerFactory.java:61)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:221)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Orb initialization erorr
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getProtocolManager(GlassFishORBHelper.java:231)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeProtocolManager(BaseContainer.java:898)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.omg.CORBA.DATA_CONVERSION: WARNING: 02410014: org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory is not a valid custom socket factory  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 14  completed: No
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.initORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:626)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.getORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBFactoryImpl.createORB(GlassFishORBFactoryImpl.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:163)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.DATA_CONVERSION: WARNING: 02410014: org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory is not a valid custom socket factory  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 14  completed: No
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy194.badCustomSocketFactory(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ParserTable$4.operate(ParserTable.java:763)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.NormalParserAction.apply(NormalParserAction.java:62)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orb.PropertyParser.parse(PropertyParser.java:84)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orb.ParserImplBase.init(ParserImplBase.java:77)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBDataParserImpl.<init>(ORBDataParserImpl.java:492)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.postInit(ORBImpl.java:562)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.set_parameters(ORBImpl.java:697)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.setParameters(ORBImpl.java:684)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.osgi.ORBFactory.initialize(ORBFactory.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.initORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:585)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: IIOP1004: Key alias s1as not found in keystore
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.<init>(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:202)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:438)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ParserTable$4.operate(ParserTable.java:755)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: IIOP1004: Key alias s1as not found in keystore
    at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.IIOPSSLUtilImpl.getKeyManagers(IIOPSSLUtilImpl.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.init(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.<init>(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:152)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: IIOP1004: Key alias s1as not found in keystore
    at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.IIOPSSLUtilImpl.getKeyManagers(IIOPSSLUtilImpl.java:93)
    ... 47 more

Severe:   Exception while loading the app
Severe:   Application deployment failed: Exception while loading the app
```

What does GlassFish Server dislike?

---

It only worked, when those files keystore.jks and cacerts.jks were regenerated using the alias name `s1as` but it fails with the given exception, when a different alias (Certificate Nickname) is used. GlassFish appears to be using this alias name for other purposes somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the same certificate alias (**s1as**) is also used for the ORB IIOP listeners.

You have to change it to your new alias.

In the Glassfish Admin UI, navigate to `server-config` - `ORB` and change the certificate alias for the different listeners in their SSL tab.

[image: ORB listeners]

Comment: Also needed to set the new nickname under `SSL_MUTUALAUTH` (the same SSL tab therein) immediately below the selected option (SSL).

Comment: Yes,  that was what I meant with you have to "change the certificate alias for the different listeners". :) The selection in the screenshot is only an example.